# Webservices Connection Issue

Tags: asp.net

I have  web service running on my Virtual Machine. Its been up and running. I am using static IP address for the VM. I am unable to access some of the methods in the service. I can access the properties but not methods. Is there anything I need to setup to access my methods?

Many Thanks
Hari Gillala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean the methods aren't showing up when you view the WSDL for the service?

Make sure you mark each service method with the [WebMethod] attribute.  Otherwise, they won't be available.

Comment: Its not the methods. I have mentioned method names as web method. It says It cannot connect to server. Using the refernce variable I can literally see all the methods/properties but cannot acccess the functionality.